# "this Apple ID has not y used with the iTunes Store tap to review " when I tap review nothing happens what do I do?

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore, apple-id

i just got a iPad mini and I set it all up. Tried to download free apps but kept saying "this Apple ID has not yet been used with iTunes Store tap to review" when I tap review nothing happens what do I do ???